# Cannot install programs with apt-get or Software Center

Tags: apt, software-center

If I try `sudo apt-get install mc` or `sudo apt-get install fortune`, I get `E: Unable to locate package mc` or `E: Unable to locate package fortune`.

Also in Ubuntu Software Center: `Use this source` is disabled.

Internet works and `wget` gets from Internet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mc` and `fortune` are both in the universe repository. Make sure you have the option to download and install packages from universe enabled.

Open software-center. Go to Edit menu --> Open software sources and check *Universe* option.

[image: software-sources-gtk]

After checking the option, run the following commands to install `mc` and `fortune`.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mc fortune
```

Comment: I tried `sudo apt-get update` and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

and then this

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and then try your commands

Comment: It would be helpful to explain *why* this sequence of commands should be executed.

Answer (score 2):

After you install Ubuntu, run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This will update the package lists and upgrade your system.

However, if you've already done so, you can follow the [instructions given by *jokerdino*](https://askubuntu.com/a/179835/74307).